# Find the coordinates of the polynomial in the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

There is a polynomial:
$$f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_nx^n$$
How to find its coordinates in the basis:
$$1,x-a,(x-a)^2,\ldots,(x-a)^n$$

Its from the task book and the answer is:
$$f'(a),\frac{f''(a)}{2!},\frac{f'''(a)}{3!},\frac{f^{n}(a)}{n!}$$

But and don't get how they came to this answer.

Comment: Look for what we call Taylor-Lagrange formula.

Comment: Have you tried computing $f'(a), f''(a)/2!$, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Let $ (a,x) \in\Bbb R^2$

$ f$ is $ C^n $ at $ [a,x]$ or $[x,a]$

The $(n+1)$ derivative of $ f $ is zero

thus, by Taylor-Lagrange formula, there exists $ c\in (a,x)$  or $ (x,a) $ such that

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}f''(a)+...+\frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)+\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n+1)}(c)$$

with $$f^{(n+1)}(c)=0$$